# Facebook mobile web app: "Page not found"

Tags: facebook, mobile, web

I have a facebook app that works without problems. To target mobile users as well, I've made a mobile version, correctly configured, that works too when accessing it seperately. However, if I click a link to the app using a mobile phone (or emulating), the redirection to the mobile site does not work: "Page not found".

Any ideas? I don't even know where an error could be since the apps both work on itself (and they both feature more or less the same code, execpt for some css).

Update: I am guessing now the problem might be this: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/450023335030232

Could this actually lead to redirecting problems?

Comment: Have you tried using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or something similar to see what redirect is failing?

Comment: Thanks, I just did. But since I am not much of a http pro, I could get any info out of it.

Answer (score 0):

It does not really solve the technical problem, but using smarturl.it I managed to evade the error.